# Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator "Test" fails

Tags: 20.04, kvm-virtualization, usb-installation, startup-disk-creator

Tried with `sudo usb-creator-gtk`
After creation tried to use the "Test" and got the following:

[image]

Tried twice - got same results both times.

System Info:
[image]

ISO Image:
`ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: Have you [verified the integrity](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) of the `.iso`? It may be an incomplete download ...

Comment: LGTM: ```$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS

gpg: Signature made Thu 06 Aug 2020 16:30:35 BST
gpg:                using RSA key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: XXXXXX
$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```